# Can't compile Plots

Tags: installation, error-handling, julia, plots.jl, julia-plots

I installed a new version of Julia, version 1.7.
And while trying to install Plots, I had the following error. I did `] add Plots` and `] build Plots` without any errors.

```
julia> using Plots
[ Info: Precompiling Plots [91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80]
ERROR: LoadError: InitError: could not load library "/home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/artifacts/4487a7356408c3a92924e56f9d3891724855282c/lib/libXau.so"
/home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/artifacts/4487a7356408c3a92924e56f9d3891724855282c/lib/libXau.so: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
Stacktrace:
  [1] dlopen(s::String, flags::UInt32; throw_error::Bool)
    @ Base.Libc.Libdl ./libdl.jl:117
  [2] dlopen(s::String, flags::UInt32)
    @ Base.Libc.Libdl ./libdl.jl:117
  [3] macro expansion
    @ ~/.julia/packages/JLLWrappers/QpMQW/src/products/library_generators.jl:54 [inlined]
  [4] __init__()
    @ Xorg_libXau_jll ~/.julia/packages/Xorg_libXau_jll/z2hT9/src/wrappers/x86_64-linux-gnu.jl:8
  [5] _include_from_serialized(path::String, depmods::Vector{Any})
    @ Base ./loading.jl:768
  [6] _require_search_from_serialized(pkg::Base.PkgId, sourcepath::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:854
  [7] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1097
  [8] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1013
  [9] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:997
 [10] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base ./Base.jl:418
 [11] top-level scope
    @ ~/.julia/packages/JLLWrappers/QpMQW/src/toplevel_generators.jl:188
 [12] include
    @ ./Base.jl:418 [inlined]
 [13] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source
::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1318
 [14] top-level scope
    @ none:1
 [15] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [16] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:453
 [17] top-level scope
    @ none:1
during initialization of module Xorg_libXau_jll
in expression starting at /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/packages/Xorg_libxcb_jll/nMYKH/src/wrappers/x86_64-linux-gnu.jl:5
in expression starting at /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/packages/Xorg_libxcb_jll/nMYKH/src/Xorg_libxcb_jll.jl:2
    ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile Xorg_libxcb_jll [c7cfdc94-dc32-55de-ac96-5a1b8d977c5b] to /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/compiled/v1.7/Xorg_libxcb_jll/jl_IJgtUS.
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base ./error.jl:33
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1466
  [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1410
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1120
  [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1013
  [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:997
  [7] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base ./Base.jl:418
  [8] top-level scope
    @ ~/.julia/packages/JLLWrappers/QpMQW/src/toplevel_generators.jl:188
  [9] include
    @ ./Base.jl:418 [inlined]
 [10] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1318
 [11] top-level scope
    @ none:1
 [12] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [13] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:453
 [14] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/packages/Xorg_libX11_jll/ICRWq/src/wrappers/x86_64-linux-gnu.jl:4
in expression starting at /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/packages/Xorg_libX11_jll/ICRWq/src/Xorg_libX11_jll.jl:2
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile Xorg_libX11_jll [4f6342f7-b3d2-589e-9d20-edeb45f2b2bc] to /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/compiled/v1.7/Xorg_libX11_jll/jl_ntTOt0.
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base ./error.jl:33
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1466
  [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1410
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1120
  [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1013
  [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:997
  [7] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base ./Base.jl:418
  [8] top-level scope
[9] include
    @ ./Base.jl:418 [inlined]
 [10] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source
::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1318
 [11] top-level scope
    @ none:1
 [12] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [13] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:453
 [14] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/packages/Cairo_jll/HW4xi/src/wrappers/x86_64-linux-gnu.jl:10
in expression starting at /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/packages/Cairo_jll/HW4xi/src/Cairo_jll.jl:2
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile Cairo_jll [83423d85-b0ee-5818-9007-b63ccbeb887a] to /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/compiled/v1.7/Cairo_jll/jl_YPjkuT.
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base ./error.jl:33
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1466
  [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1410
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1120
  [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1013
  [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:997
  [7] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base ./Base.jl:418
  [8] top-level scope
    @ ~/.julia/packages/JLLWrappers/QpMQW/src/toplevel_generators.jl:188
  [9] include
    @ ./Base.jl:418 [inlined]
 [10] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1318
 [11] top-level scope
    @ none:1
 [12] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [13] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:453
 [14] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/packages/HarfBuzz_jll/zavaV/src/wrappers/x86_64-linux-gnu.jl:4
in expression starting at /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/packages/HarfBuzz_jll/zavaV/src/HarfBuzz_jll.jl:2
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile HarfBuzz_jll [2e76f6c2-a576-52d4-95c1-20adfe4de566] to /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/compiled/v1.7/HarfBuzz_jll/jl_qkmYhc.
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base ./error.jl:33
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1466
  [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1410
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1120
  [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1013
  [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:997
  [7] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base ./Base.jl:418
  [8] top-level scope
    @ ~/.julia/packages/JLLWrappers/QpMQW/src/toplevel_generators.jl:188
  [9] include
    @ ./Base.jl:418 [inlined]
 [10] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1318
 [11] top-level scope
    @ none:1
 [12] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [13] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:453
 [14] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/packages/libass_jll/SaaQW/src/wrappers/x86_64-linux-gnu.jl:6
in expression starting at /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/packages/libass_jll/SaaQW/src/libass_jll.jl:2
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile libass_jll [0ac62f75-1d6f-5e53-bd7c-93b484bb37c0] to /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/compiled/v1.7/libass_jll/jl_Na90wC.
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base ./error.jl:33
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1466
  [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1410
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1120
  [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1013
  [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:997
  [7] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base ./Base.jl:418
  [8] top-level scope
    @ ~/.julia/packages/JLLWrappers/QpMQW/src/toplevel_generators.jl:188
  [9] include
    @ ./Base.jl:418 [inlined]
 [10] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1318
 [11] top-level scope
    @ none:1
 [12] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [13] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:453
 [14] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/packages/FFMPEG_jll/ECokx/src/wrappers/x86_64-linux-gnu.jl:4
in expression starting at /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/packages/FFMPEG_jll/ECokx/src/FFMPEG_jll.jl:2
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile FFMPEG_jll [b22a6f82-2f65-5046-a5b2-351ab43fb4e5] to /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/compiled/v1.7/FFMPEG_jll/jl_WqXB6W.
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base ./error.jl:33
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1466
  [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1410
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1120
  [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1013
  [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:997
  [7] include
    @ ./Base.jl:418 [inlined]
  [8] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1318
  [9] top-level scope
    @ none:1
 [10] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [11] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:453
 [12] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/packages/FFMPEG/OUpap/src/FFMPEG.jl:1
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile FFMPEG_jll [b22a6f82-2f65-5046-a5b2-351ab43fb4e5] to /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/compiled/v1.7/FFMPEG_jll/jl_WqXB6W.
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base ./error.jl:33
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1466
  [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1410
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1120
  [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1013
  [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:997
  [7] include
    @ ./Base.jl:418 [inlined]
  [8] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1318
  [9] top-level scope
    @ none:1
 [10] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [11] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:453
 [12] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/packages/FFMPEG/OUpap/src/FFMPEG.jl:1
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile FFMPEG [c87230d0-a227-11e9-1b43-d7ebe4e7570a] to /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/compiled/v1.7/FFMPEG/jl_OjH0xW.
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base ./error.jl:33
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1466
  [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1410
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1120
  [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1013
  [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:997
  [7] include
    @ ./Base.jl:418 [inlined]
  [8] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::Nothing)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1318
  [9] top-level scope
    @ none:1
 [10] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [11] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:453
 [12] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/packages/Plots/nzdhU/src/Plots.jl:1
ERROR: Failed to precompile Plots [91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80] to /home/mylaboratory/myname/.julia/compiled/v1.7/Plots/jl_mvedww.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(s::String)
   @ Base ./error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1466
 [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1410
 [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1120
 [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1013
 [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:997
```

This is the longest error I ever had in Julia by far and I have no idea what to do from here to fix it. Thank you a lot for your kind help!

Here are my packages versions:

```
    (@v1.7) pkg> status
      Status `~/.julia/environments/v1.7/Project.toml`
  [159f3aea] Cairo v1.0.5
  [861a8166] Combinatorics v1.0.2
  [a81c6b42] Compose v0.9.3
  [7db386b5] DependencyWalker v0.1.2
  [31c24e10] Distributions v0.25.54
  [c87230d0] FFMPEG v0.4.1
  [186bb1d3] Fontconfig v0.4.0
  [59287772] Formatting v0.4.2
  [a2cc645c] GraphPlot v0.5.0
  [86223c79] Graphs v1.6.0
  [06909019] GraphsFlows v0.1.0
  [2e9cd046] Gurobi v0.9.14
  [4076af6c] JuMP v0.21.10
  [d96e819e] Parameters v0.12.3
  [f3e62ec7] PkgCleanup v0.1.0 `https://github.com/giordano/PkgCleanup.jl#main`
  [91a5bcdd] Plots v1.28.0
  [770da0de] UpdateJulia v0.4.0
  [ade2ca70] Dates
  [8bb1440f] DelimitedFiles
  [9a3f8284] Random
```

EDIT: When doing `] rm Plots ; update ; resolve ; add Plots`

I got this:

```
Precompiling project...
✗ Plots
  0 dependencies successfully precompiled in 14 seconds (145 already precompiled, 29 skipped during auto due to previous errors)
  1 dependency errored. To see a full report either run `import Pkg; Pkg.precompile()` or load the package
```

And build Plots gives the same error. Downgrading GR to v0.61.2 did not solve the issue unfortefunately

Comment: My normal set of steps when something like this happens: try doing “update” before you instead plots and try doing “resolve”. See if this resolves the issue.

Comment: @logankilpatrick, thanks for your comments. "update" and "resolve" did not fix the issue unfortunately...

Comment: Ah, I missed you already have plots installed, remove it, then run those commands, then add it back again.

Comment: @logankilpatrick
That did solve the issue unfortenately, I am editing

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here:

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.7.2
Commit bf53498635 (2022-02-06 15:21 UTC)
```

After an `] update` I had the Plots' compilation error. In the `Manifest.toml` I have

```
[[Plots]]
deps = ["Base64", "Contour", "Dates", "Downloads", "FFMPEG", "FixedPointNumbers", "GR", "GeometryBasics", "JSON", "Latexify", "LinearAlgebra", "Measures", "NaNMath", "Pkg", "PlotThemes", "PlotUtils", "Printf", "REPL", "Random", "RecipesBase", "RecipesPipeline", "Reexport", "Requires", "Scratch", "Showoff", "SparseArrays", "Statistics", "StatsBase", "UUIDs", "UnicodeFun", "Unzip"]
git-tree-sha1 = "c64338ef7b60f8458a9feaadd378261bd3279c89"
uuid = "91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80"
version = "1.28.0"
```

Fixed the issue downgrading the `GR` package from `0.64.2` to `0.64.1`

```
[[GR]]
deps = ["Base64", "DelimitedFiles", "GR_jll", "HTTP", "JSON", "Libdl", "LinearAlgebra", "Pkg", "Printf", "Random", "RelocatableFolders", "Serialization", "Sockets", "Test", "UUIDs"]
git-tree-sha1 = "df5f5b0450c489fe6ed59a6c0a9804159c22684d"
uuid = "28b8d3ca-fb5f-59d9-8090-bfdbd6d07a71"
version = "0.64.1"
```